# Forces besides gravity acting at astronomical distances?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

It seems like all one reads about is gravity affecting planets and stars whereas at the atomic level there are other forces and gravity is unimportant. How do we know there are not other forces besides gravity affecting, for example, the shape of galaxies?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we don't. Just like we don't really know if anti-matter has positive or negative gravity, or if it has gravity at all because we've been unable to measure it so far. But we assume that physics works the same everywhere in the universe and only introduce new things when it can't be explained by tweaking anything we currently have and have a lead to to go on (i.e. an avenue or framework from which to jump off of to begin investigating).

Introducing a new thing to explain a mystery just replaces one mystery for another mystery, or replaces one mystery with two mysteries which is even worse. Instead of ntroducing something for which there is no avenue or framework to begin investigation with, you might as well try on tweaking what you already have because it at least gives you some direction rather than blindly groping in the dark. If it truly cannot be tweaked, presumably, somewhere along the way of trying to tweak things you will run into some definitive evidence that you are on the wrong path which will also shed light on where to go next. It's pretty easy to see why physicists would be so hesitant to introduce something brand new whose nature essentially boils down to "we can't investigate it because we can't get to it".

And dark energy is one of those things physicists have begrudgingly been forced to introduce.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely are forces other than gravity acting at astronomical scales. Perhaps most importantly that's magnetic fields, forcing plasma to follow its field lines. The galactic magnetic field can even be made visible through its effect it has on the polarization of microwaves (composite image from Planck, Bicep2 and Keck):

[image: The lines essentially indicate the magnetic field lines in a small patch of our Milky Way galaxy. Image from https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/plancks-view-of-bicep2keck-array-field]

Further, there's [Ram pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure), which for example causes jets from Active Galactic Nuclei to puff up eventually, like this one in M87 seen by Hubble:

[image: The jet from Active Galactic Nucleus M87 puffs up towards the lower right due to Ram pressure. Image taken by the Hubble Space Telescope.]

And of course there is friction in its various forms that allows planets and stars to collapse and thus form in the first place.

Concerning the second question, we can understand and simulate the formation of galaxies using the known laws of physics with stunning accuracy. For example, these are virtual galaxies, created and evolved using the known laws of physics in a massive computer simulation. Here is an entire Hubble fork assembled from galaxies in the Illustris simulation, which closely resemble what we observe in our actual universe:

[image: An entire Hubble fork made from simulated galaxies, which closely resemble what we observe in our actual universe. Image from the Illustris simulation.]

So if there were any additional forces beyond those known to us, they can at most have a limited impact on the formation and shape of galaxies.

Finally and for the sake of completeness, what is called Dark Energy is certainly important at cosmological scales and can be thought of as a force that drives space itself apart.